# CakePHP 2.6 isAuthorized not being called

Tags: authentication, cakephp, cakephp-2.6

I have a working project that i want to extend with authentication. I followed the Simple Authentication and Authorization Tutorial [here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html).

Logging in works and i can print the Username etc. But the access control is not working. The Method isAuthorized is simply not working. What am i missing here?

Edit - I receive the below error;

```
"You are not authorized to access that location."
```

Part of my AppController:

```
public $components = array('Flash', 'RequestHandler', 'Cookie', 'Session', 'Auth' => array(
        'loginRedirect' => array(
            'controller' => 'status',
            'action' => 'index'
        ),
        'logoutRedirect' => array(
            'controller' => 'user',
            'action' => 'login'
        ),
        'authenticate' => array(
            'Form' => array(
                'passwordHasher' => 'Blowfish'
            ),
        ),
        'authorize' => array('Controller')
    ));

public function isAuthorized($user)
{
    if (isset($user['role']) && $user['role'] === 'admin') return true;

    return false;
}
```

Part of my taskController:

```
public function isAuthorized($user)
{
    debug($user); die();

    if ($this->action === 'index') return true;

    if (in_array($this->action, array('edit', 'delete')))
    {
        $postId = (int) $this->request->params['pass'][0];
        if ($this->Post->isOwnedBy($postId, $user['id'])) return true;
    }

    return parent::isAuthorized($user);
}
```

Part of UsersController:

```
public function login()
{
    if ($this->request->is('post'))
    {
        if ($this->Auth->login())
        {
            return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl()); // This is being called after login so it seems to work!
        }

        $this->Flash->error(__('Invalid username or password, try again'));
    }
}
```

Comment: When you say the method isn't working - what's the actual error message you're getting?

Comment: "You are not authorized to access that location." is all i get back.

Comment: Probably not related to the error, but you have `debug($user); die();` in your `isAuthorized` method in taskController?

Comment: Just to check if the method gets called and whatever i try, it does not get called. If it got called i would notice the debug output of $user of course.

Comment: Please provide the path (`/controller/action/param`) you are calling.

Comment: It happens with every path because i haven't added anything to the allow-list. /auftrag/index/ /auftrag/view/12, /status/index, /status/view/3. Being redirected to the login-page over and over and isauthorized is not getting called.

Comment: I tried to check if the the user is logged in after the login-action. It seems that the user is not. After redirecting the user to a different location, "$this->Auth->loggedIn()" returns false. Also "$this->Auth->User()" returns null. How is it possible that "$this-Auth->login()" returns true to log the user in but then the user is not logged in?